# Custom Searchfield properties to customize the text "No Data"

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have created a search-field in SAPUI5 using XML.

The search field works properly but whenever I enter a search value which is not valid, it returns "No Data", which is correct.

I want to edit the "No Data" phrase and customize it to my own phrase like this: "No info returned for this search"

How do i accomplish it? Here is my current code below.

```
    <Searchfield>
    search ="searchMethod"
    width = "100%"
    id = "doSearch"
    </searchfield>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in **controller** in `onInit()` or `onDataLoaded()`

```
this.byId("yourListId").setNoDataText("No info returned for this search");
```

OR in **XML** itself you can set

```
<List noDataText="No info returned for this search" />
```